# How to stop the Divi theme from loading Google fonts

Tags: fonts

I want to host Google fonts locally to hopefully shave some page loading time off.

I hope to use [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) to do this.

I would need to ensure our theme, Divi, does not load the original Google fonts.

Currently, our site has the following in the head.

```
<link data-asynced='1' as='style' onload='this.rel="stylesheet"'  rel='preload' id='divi-fonts-css'  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&#038;subset=latin,latin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

In `/Divi/core/functions.php`, there is:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_core_get_main_fonts' ) ) :
function et_core_get_main_fonts() {
    global $wp_version;

    if ( version_compare( $wp_version, '4.6', '<' ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $fonts_url = '';

    /* Translators: If there are characters in your language that are not
     * supported by Open Sans, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate
     * into your own language.
     */
    $open_sans = _x( 'on', 'Open Sans font: on or off', 'Divi' );

    if ( 'off' !== $open_sans ) {
        $font_families = array();

        if ( 'off' !== $open_sans )
            $font_families[] = 'Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800';

        $protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
        $query_args = array(
            'family' => implode( '%7C', $font_families ),
            'subset' => 'latin,latin-ext',
        );
        $fonts_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, "$protocol://fonts.googleapis.com/css" );
    }

    return $fonts_url;
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'et_core_load_main_fonts' ) ) :
function et_core_load_main_fonts() {
    $fonts_url = et_core_get_main_fonts();
    if ( empty( $fonts_url ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'et-core-main-fonts', esc_url_raw( $fonts_url ), array(), null );
}
endif;
```

How would I stop the Divi theme from loading the Google font?

Do I need to disable the function `et_core_load_main_fonts` ?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: Yes I am using a child theme Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone has already done what I need to do.

From [this post](https://designsbytierney.com/2017/06/optimize-google-font-delivery-wordpress-divi-theme/), I can add the following code to my child theme's `functions.php`:

```
// REMOVE OPEN SANS GOOGLE FONT FROM DIVI
function disable_open_sans_divi() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'divi-fonts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_open_sans_divi', 20 );
```

Comment: You need to change `divi-fonts` to `et-core-main-fonts`, since that's the name of the style being added from your code that you said you wanted removed.

Answer (score 2):

[wp_dequeue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) should help you. You should dequeue style and enqueue your fonts.

```
wp_dequeue_style('et-core-main-fonts');
wp_enqueue_style('your_fonts_handle', 'path_to_your_fonts');
```

Or redeclare function with your fonts.

```
et_core_load_main_fonts() {
    $fonts_url = et_core_get_main_fonts();
    if ( empty( $fonts_url ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'et-core-main-fonts', esc_url_raw( 'path_to_your_style' ), array(), null );
}
```